# Visual Studio 2015 Closes directly after starting it without any error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Visual studio 2015 closes directly after I launch it, 
and that happened after I update the windows 10.
is there any files missed after the update ?
thanks.

Comment: Maybe. Windows 10 can *move* application files. Try repairing Visual Studio

Comment: unfortunately, repairing didn't work.

Comment: do you see any error entry in event log?